# Как реализовать это небольшое окно слева с выбором и скроллом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

[image: Скролл слева]

Как сверстать этот кусок окна слева? Нужен какой-то сторонний помощник или на чистом html ,css можно сделать ?

Comment: Чистейший HTML/CSS, причем несложный. Почитайте основы, что ли.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.block{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bl-right{
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.bl-right:before { 
   content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.bl-right:hover{
  border-right: 5px solid #00CB85;
  
}
.bl-right:hover:before{
  color: #00CB85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/421d417066.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="bl-right">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы начинающий фронтендер, то напишите это на чистом html, css, js. Тогда лучше разберетесь что к чему и для чего.

Сделаю намётки:

```js
Javascript

// описываем каждый из элементов контрола
// не забываем про ресайз окна window.on('resize', function(){});
// не забываем про touch события для моб. устройств touchEvents (touchStart, touchEnd, touchMove)
```

```css
Css

.scrollbar {overflow: hidden; height: статическое значение в px} // убираем нативный скролл
.scroll-area {overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100%;}
```

```html
 HTML

<div class="scrollbar">
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="scroll-controls">
      <span class="c-arr-top"></span>
      <span class="c-drag"></span>
      <span class="c-arr-bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```